# Joining / merging two data frames by symmetric differences in rows and columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to join / merge two data frames, but ignoring similarities in rows and columns in the resulting data frame. Consider the following example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  id = c("a","b","c"),
  a = runif(3,1,9),
  b = runif(3,1,9)
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  df1[1:2,],
  c = runif(2,1,9)
)
```

Results in two data frames that have exactly **four cells** in common (not counting `id`), so `df1[1:2,2:3] == df2[1:2,2:3]`. However, they do differ in regard that `df1` as an additional row and `df2` has an additional column:

```
> print(df1)
  id        a        b
1  a 6.396168 4.037320
2  b 4.119025 8.181253
3  c 5.608775 4.219469

> print(df2)
  id        a        b        c
1  a 6.396168 4.037320 2.444122
2  b 4.119025 8.181253 6.444280
```

I want a new data frame to consist of the [symmetric differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) between these two, so no duplicates in rows or columns. The closest result I have achieved is by using `dplyr::full_join(df1, df2, by = "id")`, but this results in duplicated columns.

The result should look like this:

```
  id        a        b        c
1  a 6.396168 4.037320 2.444122
2  b 4.119025 8.181253 6.444280
3  c 5.608775 4.219469       NA
```

What's the best way of achieving this dynamically? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `data.table` we can join on the 'id' and assign the 'c' from the second dataset to create the 'c' column in the first data.  By default, the non-matching elements will be assigned as `NA`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df2, c := c, on = .(id)]
df1
#   id        a        b        c
#1:  a 4.601639 1.065642 7.476494
#2:  b 6.065758 6.234421 8.929932
#3:  c 4.000351 7.365717       NA
```

NOTE: The values are different as there was not set seed

---

In `base R`, an option would be `match`

```
df1$c <- df2$c[match(df1$id, df2$id)]
```

---

Regarding the OP's use of `full_join` (`left_join` would be fine based on the example), the trick is to remove the columns that are not needed in the second dataset

```
library(dplyr)
nm1 <- c("id", setdiff(names(df2), names(df1)))
left_join(df1, select(df2, nm1), by = 'id')
```

Comment: Thanks! The dplyr-solution appears to be most promising thus far, although, it doesn't work when `df1 <- df2` and `df2 <- df1`. How would you make it work both ways?

Comment: @ComfortEagle  In that case you have to switch the names in `setdiff`

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case this would be sufficient

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select * from df1 left natural join df2")
##   id        a        b        c
## 1  a 6.396168 4.037320 2.444122
## 2  b 4.119025 8.181253 6.444280
## 3  c 5.608775 4.219469       NA
```

or with dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df1, df2)
```

but in general  you might need the following.  Note this is perfectly general. We did not need to specify the column or row names in either the above or following code and in the following code it is symmetric in `df1` and `df2` so it does not rely on knowing the structure of either.

```
sqldf("select * from df1 left natural join df2
union
select * from df2 left natural join df1")
##   id        a        b        c
## 1  a 6.396168 4.037320 2.444122
## 2  b 4.119025 8.181253 6.444280
## 3  c 5.608775 4.219469       NA
```

or with dplyr.  This will give a warning but still works.  You can avoid the warning if `id` were character rather than factor or if you convert it to character first.

```
library(dplyr)
rbind(left_join(df1, df2), left_join(df2, df1)) %>% distinct
```

### Note

Because the question did not use `set.seed` the code to generate the input is 
not reproducible but we can copy the particular `df1` and `df2` so that we have the same data as in the question.

```
Lines1 <- "
  id        a        b
1  a 6.396168 4.037320
2  b 4.119025 8.181253
3  c 5.608775 4.219469"
df1 <- read.table(text = Lines1)

Lines2 <- "
  id        a        b        c
1  a 6.396168 4.037320 2.444122
2  b 4.119025 8.181253 6.444280"
df2 <- read.table(text = Lines2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach if one of the data frames has all the rows you want (df2 here):

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df2, anti_join(df1, df2))

#Joining, by = c("id", "a", "b")
#  id        a        b        c
#1  a 1.912298 5.792475 6.899253
#2  b 2.537666 1.495075 1.186120
#3  c 5.947766 6.594028       NA
```